# Antlr4 switch the lexer mode programatically

Tags: antlr4

I would like to be able to define programmatically to which mode the lexer should switch. Say if I have a grammar that parses something like php code.

```
foo bar <?php ...   ?>
```

but in my case it will support more than one language, say

```
foo bar <?php ... ?> 
baz <?cpp ... ?> 
blah <?java ... ?>
```

the problem is that I would like to have one of the languages to be by default, but which one could be determined only programmatically, say based on the file extension. Or if the file is `something.cpp-tmpl`

```
<? ... ?>
```

to switch to cpp mode, for the same construction in file with name `something.java-tmpl` to switch to java mode.

Can I, and if yes, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.  Look at `org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.java` for a full complement of methods for programmatically managing lexer modes.  These are implicitly the mode control statements surfaced in Antlr lexer grammars.